# always return Invalid Product ID in in app purchase(iap)

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

**I have done following things....**

1) Bundle identifier is same in both app id and XCode bundle identifier

2) Agreement and tax banking completed successfully

3) Enable In App Purchase enable in capabilities and also in app id

4) Regenerate Provisioning profile

5) Create App ID Successfully with information...

6) Uninstall app then reinstall But not working

7) Restart device

8) Create SandBox User Account and login to my device

I tried all the steps but not working...

**every time return invalid product id...Why?**

Comment: How do you obtain ProductID?

Comment: Show the relevant code.

Comment: @andrify_fedin and rmaddy check it my code
 if SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments() {
            let productIdentifiersmy: Set<ProductIdentifier> = ["productID"]
            var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiersmy)
            productsRequest.delegate = self
            productsRequest.start()
        }
        else {
            print("Сan't make purchases")
        }

Comment: didReceive method
func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        print("Got the request from Apple")
        response.invalidProductIdentifiers.forEach() { id in
            print(id)
        }
        let count: Int = response.products.count
        if count > 0 {
            let myProduct = response.products
            for product in myProduct {
                iapProducts.append(product)
            }
}

Answer (score 1):

I wish you added bank details in 'Agreement,Tax and banking' tab in App Store connect.

[image]

Comment: oh this was a real mystery for me too, good call